# How to Store HTML file into Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty much new to ROR and i'm stuck in storing html file into rails model. Can anyone help me to show how do we store HTML static file into rails model and also how to render? Thanks in advance i apologize if this question is too basic i could not find solution for this anywhere

Comment: Html code can be stored  in `column_type:text` and in view page it can be shown as `model_object.column_name.htm_safe` . there can be better alternative  for this.

Comment: Much appreciated  However my concern was how do we store it into that column once we create model with two column names ? Like how do we store it into that column? Could you please help me understand. Thanks again @Gabbar

Comment: You have this HTML file on disk somewhere? Open the file, read it into a string, close the file, send that string into your model instance just like setting any other attribute. Am I missing something?

Comment: Read it into string? I don't really get that. So i've html file so first thing i wanted to move this file into rails model column? how do i do that ? ill make that simple first step. Thanks gabbar

Comment: @Mun Can you show any code samples, what have you tried so far for better implementation.

Comment: Just for example imagine i've this html file
 . %body  #container 
    %header 
      %h1 Our Awesome Haml Template 
    #main Abstracting HTML since 2006 
    %footer 
      %address Ian Oxley
 How do i move this into rails model coulmn

Comment: Do you have path of that file? or you will copy that code manually?

Comment: I can do both actually. I have path or i can copy that code manually.

Comment: does not really matter as long as i know how i save my html file into rails model column. It would be great help if you be able to let me know the steps. Much thanks

Comment: In case if you want to copy code html code manually just copy it and in column save it as i suggested in first comment, in case if you want to read html file by path you have to read file and returned string will be saved

Comment: so you mean once i create model and run migrations it will create table so you just copy that html file in there ? That's wha you mean @Gabbar

Comment: @mun yes. Copy HTML file mean copy code of that HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this small project can help you with your question. I made here small rails project where you can insert like post with title and body which is HTML content.
Also you can edit it and show it. Maybe you need also reading html file from filesystem that is not implemented but it is not too complex to do that also:

Please check project on link:https://github.com/nezirz/save_html

Here is screenshot of fields where you are inserting/saving html to model/db.
[image]

[image]